# Why does the variable not change its value after admin action has been triggered?

Tags: python, django, testing

I have two admin actions for the Feedback Model in the admin panel, approved and unapproved.
The value for `approved` in the Feedback Model is default to `False`. When admin use the action to approve, it turns this value to `True` and unapproved will turn `True` to `False`. This works on the admin panel on the deployed site, however when I'm trying to do the test for the admin.py I ran into an error where the test_approve is passing, while the test_unapprove failed.

When I try to debug the test_unapprove I set the `approved` value as `True` and then check the value of feedback.approve before the `response` and it came out as `True`, which is expected. Then I check again after the `response` and it still came out as `True` where it should come out as `False`. Please have a look if you have any clue why this is happening. If you need any more info please let me know!

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Feedback)
class FeedbackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('username', 'body', 'lesson_id', 'created_on', 'approved')
    list_filter = ('approved', 'created_on')
    list_display_links = ('username',)
    search_fields = ['username', 'user_id', 'body']
    actions = ['approved_feedback', 'unapproved_feedback']

    def approved_feedback(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(approved=True)

    def unapproved_feedback(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(approved=False)
```

test_admin.py

```
class TestAdmin(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(self):
        # Create a superuser for admin login
        self.admin_user = User.objects.create_superuser(
            username='admin',
            password='adminpassword',
            email='admin@email.com'
        )

        self.feedback = Feedback.objects.create(
            lesson=self.lesson,
            username=self.user,
            email='user1@email.com',
            body='Feedback 1',
        )

    # Check if admin user can approve feedback
    def test_admin_approve_feedback(self):
        self.client.login(username='admin', password='adminpassword')
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('admin:roller_criu_app_feedback_changelist'),
            {
                'action': 'approved_feedback',
                '_selected_action': [self.feedback.id],
            }
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.feedback.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertTrue(self.feedback.approved)

    # Check if admin user can unapprove feedback
    def test_admin_unapprove_feedback(self):
        self.client.login(username='admin', password='adminpassword')
        self.feedback.approved = True
        self.feedback.save()

        print(f'Feedback.approved before action: {self.feedback.approved}')
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('admin:roller_criu_app_feedback_changelist'),
            {
                'action': 'unapproved_feedback',
                '_selected_action': [str(self.feedback.id)],
            }
        )
        print(f'Feedback.approved after action: {self.feedback.approved}') # this prints out True, and should be False
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        feedback.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertFalse(feedback.approved)
```